# Get last 5 lines of a file in Hadoop (HDFS)

Tags: hadoop

I have several files in my Hadoop cluster (on HDFS). I want to see the last 5 lines of every file. Is there a simple command to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see the last 5 lines specifically (and not any more or any less) of a file in HDFS, you can use the following command but its not very efficient:

`hadoop fs -cat /your/file/with/path | tail -5`

Here's a more efficient command within hadoop, but it returns the last kilobyte of the data, not a user-specified number of lines:

`hadoop fs -tail /your/file/with/path`

Here's a reference to the `hadoop tail` command : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#tail

Comment: hadoop fs -tail /your/file/with/path this command will give me last 10 lines, How can I default it to some number of my own. Is it possible in HDFS..
As in linux we can write tail -20f <filename>